# iPython Notebook (Python 3): ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, I am really a python idiot, and this is my first python test.

I am running a `test_predictors.ipynb` file using [Jupyter](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I ran into an "ImportError: No module named" error when executing the `test_predictors.ipynb` file by block, like following:

[image]

The `decisioni_tree.py` is another .py file in the same folder as `test_predictors.ipynb`. `calculate_information_gain, decision_tree_train, decision_tree_predict` are all functions defined in `decisioni_tree.py`. The following picture is showing the file layout:

[image]

I searched a lot of threads, tried putting all .py files into a subfolder, or adding a leading dot in front of `decisioni_tree`, or adding full path to `decisioni_tree`, but none of these worked.

I also read [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), but it does not make much sense to me. Now I am really clueless. I guess it was the path problem, but I don't figure out the logic behind how python arrange their path. I am wondering anyone can give some pointers? How should I solve this problem? Thanks.

I am using Windows 10, with I think Python 3.4/3.5 installed.

Comment: I barely use Jupyter notebooks, so this is a stab in the dark. What happens if you create an empty file in the same directory called `__init__.py` (double underscore on each side) and then try?

Comment: @roganjosh, that was my first thought. I don't have any issues importing from a local .py file with Jupyter on Ubuntu. Worth a shot though - could be that Windows behaves differently.

Comment: @roganjosh I added an empty file named  $__init__.py$  like you suggested, but unfortunately the same error occurred.

Comment: Have you tried to restart kernel?

Comment: @Sraw Sorry, I am really python newbie. How to restart kernel? I can try to restart Jupyter, but I don't know if that restarts the kernel.

Comment: @Sraw So I restarted Jupyter, deleted 'test_predictors.ipynb' from the Jupyter webpage, then re-added, ran it, but the same error occurred. I don't know if I restarted kernel?

Comment: Yes you definitely restart kernel if you restart whole jupyter. Could you try to create a `test.py` which only contains `import decisioni_tree`? And could you try to copy all these files to a normal folder?

Comment: @Sraw OK I created a folder called "normal" in the same folder as $$test_predictors.ipynb$$, then I cut all the .py files into the normal folder. then I created test.py file which only contains import decision_tree, and this test.py file is in the same folder as normal folder and test_predictors.ipynb. I don't know if I am doing what you mean? I guess I also don't know what I am doing.

Comment: I mean you can try to run `test.py` to test if it is a problem about jupyter. If running in normal python script works well, it may be a problem related to jupyter. And I suppose if it is caused by your folder is a sync folder of dropbox. What I mean `normal folder` is exactly a common, normal folder.

Comment: @Sraw I copy the whole folder to a non-sync place instead of dropbox, still the problem occurred. Then I use command line to execute the test.py  which only has the import decision_tree line, nothing happened, no error message, just nothing. What does that mean?

Comment: It exit too fast to make sense. Add a line `input()` to block the script.

Comment: @Sraw Yeah, now it stops there for the input like the C++ getchar(). So that means test.py works with no problem?

Comment: Yeah, so there is no problem about your scripts structure. All problems are caused by jupyter. Try reinstall jupyter or don't load `auto reload` (delete first cell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'directory_of_the_pyfile_you_want_to_import')

import FOLDER.file
```

where `FOLDER` is the module name and `file is the .py file` you want to import.

This if the `__init__.py` solution don't work..

Comment: Looks like It works. I am no longer getting the error message I have been getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you cannot import any script from your working directory.
This shouldn't be happening.
I suggest you take a look at your python paths by running in your notebook:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

if your home directory or directory of notebooks, something like `'C:\\Users\\yourusername\\.ipython'` doesn't show up then you probably need add it as a path.
try adding your home directory to path:

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\yourusername\\')
```

or

```
sys.path.insert(1, 'C:\\Users\\yourusername\\')
```

Comment: 'C:\Users\yourusername\.ipython'  actually shows up when I print(sys.path). So what now?